# dotnet run - launchSettings.json Environment variables not set on Mac

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

We have a `launchSettings.json` in our `asp.net core` project. In there, we set some environment variables.
When we run `dotnet run`, the profile from `launchSettings` is used and environment vars set correctly.

One of our developers tried to use do the same on MacOS. When running `dotnet run` it reports that `launchSettings` is used, but no environment variables are set. We've tried running it as root user and it had no impact.

Are we doing something wrong or is it some known issue?

Comment: have you tried creating a app directly on mac and running? `dotnet new mvc -o sample`

If it runs, you can check up it's `launchSettings.json` file

Comment: We are having the same problem with all .NET Core 2.2 web applications. When we deploy them off the developers workstation, the web apps will not run in IIS because it thinks the environment variable is set to 'Development'.
We have set the environment in Windows, in the project json files, web.xml, and even in the Main() method.
The environment variable is not working with a sample application, which did work in Core 2.0 and 2.1.
We opened a bug in .NET Core 2.2 and have given up after weeks of effort and gone back to .NET 4.57 for REST services.